# Override parts of Activity class from TestProject

Tags: java, android, testing, overriding

I have two projects, a SourceProject and a TestProject. In the Source-Project I have the following class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i("", "normal mode");
    }
}
```

In my test project I'd like to change/override the log message for example. Of course I can do the following and just put the new class under the same package path and change the class as following:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i("", "test mode");
    }
}
```

But let's say I have much more functionality in my class and would like to use this functionality (in my test class as well). I can't just extend my SourceProject-Class "MyActivity" because it's named equally. But if I change the name to "MyActivityX extends MyActivity" it obviously doesn't get compiled into the application.

Does anyone have a solution, which doesn't require me to copy the complete source class to the test project and modify it there?

Answer (score 0):

If you work under Linux you could have a link instead of a file in one of your projects.

```
$ ln -s {/path/to/file-name} {link-name}
```

I don't know if there are links under Windows.

Comment: But then I couldn't modify it for my test purposes. It would be essentially the same as not having this file in my test project at all.

Comment: You can try using some version control system, have several branches for the same file, merge as needed. Try Git or Svn.